# FTP/SFTP pick latest file

Tags: ftp, mule

I have an inbound SFTP where a third party vendor drops files. I need to pick only the latest file. Is there a way to do this without moving the file or deleting previous files? I am using Mule 3.6.2 EE. Thanks.

Regards,
Hari

Comment: I think there is a "fileAge" attribute you can set.

Comment: Thanks Ana. fileAge  is to wait for a specified period of time before processing to start. My requirement is to pick the last file dropped. It could have been 2 days back or 20 minutes back- Hari

Comment: Very good question, this is an important need and we see another case where mule sucks

Comment: @hpandalai how did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you have to create a java class.Make use of mule provided org.mule.transport.sftp library.Inside java you have to sort the files based on last modified date.

Regards,
Prashanth Anuganti.